# How to Determine the Type of Abstract Input Ports after a System Has Been Constructed?

Tags: drake

I'm trying to automate the declaration of output ports in one system (System A) based on the input ports of another system (System B). My approach involves constructing System B first and then passing it into the `__init__` function of System A.

For vector-valued ports, this process is straightforward since I can retrieve the size of the vector input ports of System B and declare corresponding vector output ports in System A accordingly. However, I'm struggling with abstract ports.

I attempted to create a default context for System B and then evaluate the abstract input ports using that context (`absract_value = B.input_port.Eval(context)`), hoping to infer the abstract value. However, since the ports haven't been connected yet, I encountered a runtime error.

Is there a method or workaround to determine the type (or structure) of abstract input ports in a Drake system without connecting or evaluating them? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [pydrake.systems.framework.InputPort.Allocate](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.systems.framework.html#pydrake.systems.framework.InputPort.Allocate) as in `system_b.get_input_port(i).Allocate()` to create a sample value using the input port's type.

Comment: This works. Thank you!  : )